# Does seating sit or stand?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

A new Wikipedia page (Theatre of Nero, July 2023) includes

> The first structure . . can thus be identified with the cavea of the theatre, where the tiers of seats for the audience stood . . .

Something seems obviously anomalous here, despite an intuition to prefer "the chair stood on the platform" and "the chair sat on the platform" and without any rules requiring this.

Comment: As a German, I do not have a reliable intuition on Englsh, but are you sure that the problem is with "seats...stood" and not rather with "tiers ... stood"? Because a tier is not a vertical structure (as opposed to a chair).

Comment: Agreed with @Alazon – it’s the tiers, not the seats, that stand. I wouldn’t fit “where the seats for the audience sat” very idiomatic either – people sit in the seats, but the seats themselves stand on the floor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the English language site, not linguistics.

Comment: What seems anomalous? It sounds fine to me.

Comment: What @alphabet said. I have no problem with [where the chairs sat](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22where+the+chairs+sat%22) OR [where the chairs stood](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22where+the+chairs+stood%22). In fact, i doubt many native speakers would even notice anything unusual about those (I wouldn't, if it hadn't been raised here). Come to that, in a conversational context, I probably wouldn't even notice [where the **seats sat**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22where+the+seats+sat%22) (which apparently a witness in a court case said! :)

Comment: I suppose that using 'sit' for non-sitting–species/inanimate items is a metaphorical usage, while 'stand' didn't require a sitting-species subject referent when it entered the language. This might suggest that 'stand' works better for non-sitting–species/inanimate objects such as _seats_ or _tiers_ of seats, but here 'the seats were seated ...' etc sound rather ridiculous in any case.

Comment: Something seems anomalous in your last sentence: There is an intuition to prefer "the chair stood on the platform" and "the chair sat on the platform" over what? (I suspect that you meant the former over the latter.)

Comment: Tiers stand tall. I don’t know what else would have been in this theater, but compare something less height-y, e.g., *the ropes sat on the floor*.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the question is here. The OP suspects that there might be something wrong with the quoted formulation, but does not present the reasons for that suspicion; without such an explanation one cannot even start thinking about whether the suspicion is warranted. An explication of the reasons for the suspicion is needed, because there is nothing **obviously** wrong with the quoted formulation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your first link is quite interesting, actually. I would never use _sit_ with chairs in the straightforward context of describing where some chairs happen to be currently located – I’d always use _stand_ for that. I would only use it to describe chairs if they were ‘abandoned’ (e.g., “the chair sat unused in the corner”) or in storage (“the back room where the chairs and tables sit between events”). _[Side note: ‘fit’ in my first comment above should have read ‘find’, of course.]_

Comment: I'd vote to pass it back to Linguistics in the hope that someone might know of a language where situation and function could affect each other's description. Here, I see a chair or a single seat playing the same part as any other piece of furniture. We might more likely say a tall wardrobe stood or a long, low chest lay and by that token a bench or a tier or two of seats might lie rather than sit or stand. However, that's all about form, not function.

Comment: The COCA corpus has 26 hits for "chair sat" and 21 for "chair stood", which surprises me a bit - although some of each may well be cases of inversion (e.g. "on the chair stood/sat a vase"). Regardless, either should be fine.

Comment: Also worth noting that a *stand* (like a music stand) may also sit or stand. Both just indicate existence in some location with some slight connotation about the height of the object (you would probably say the carpet sat, rather than stood, in the center of the room).

Comment: I can't stand sitting!!!